# Pass in a file name

Tags: java, try-catch, filenames

So I am working on some assignments that are basically tutorials for coding in Java. These tasks are not for a grade I am just trying to teach myself coding in Java. The task at hand is to call in a file name but without hard-coding it. The name passed in is then supposed to be a parameter. The code I have so far is:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Music 
{
    private String songTitle;
    private String albumName;
    private String artistName;
    private int releaseYear;
    static String[] arrayTitles=new String[12];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
    try
    {
        String path=args[0];
        File music=new File(path);

        Scanner readLibrary=new Scanner(music);
        int numberOfTitles=readLibrary.nextInt();
        System.out.println(numberOfTitles);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
    {
        System.out.println("ERROR!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Where I have 
    String path=args[0];
is where I am receiving my error.
I can simply put the file name "music.txt" and the program works. So I am only trying to get this code to work with any file input.
The file music.txt is already in my workspace.
I am using Eclipse.

Comment: You can check `args.length` to see how many args got passed in. But, what would you want `path` to be if there's no argument?

Comment: Are you running your java program from console?

Comment: *where I am receiving my error*. What error? Your post says nothing about an error, doesn't explain an error, doesn't include an error message of any sort, and in fact doesn't even indicate that you have any problem with the code you've posted at all. You've also not asked any sort of question. What specifically is the problem you're experiencing, and what specifically are you asking?

Comment: So I do not have any args passed in according to args.length. Is there a way to pass in any file as an argument?

Comment: The error I am getting is:

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
 at Music.main(Music.java:23)

Comment: I am also running from the IDE, I just click run.

Comment: Your IDE's run configurations should have the ability to pass in program arguments. How it does it specifically is going to be up to your IDE. But it should be called "run configurations" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

This is happening because `args[0]` is null. You aren't staring your java program from command line. If you want that `args[0]` not to be null, than use in your command line this line of code:

> java Music music.txt

Hope it helps.

Comment: This doesn't seem like it would work for a random file to be used instead such as "example.txt"

Comment: Of course it does. Just run it as ":java Music example.txt"

Comment: It will run for your `example.txt`, too. @FredK. Thanks Fred.

Answer (score 1):

In eclipse you should go to:

Run > Run Configurations > Java Application > "Select your main class" > Go to Tab "Arguments" > In section "Programn Arguments" you can define your path as you want

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what the rules are for your practice assignment, but to avoid having to run the program from the command line and to help stay within the confines of your IDE, you could prompt the user for the filename or path and pass it through as a variable. That should work for any filename, but puts the responsibility on the user to know exactly what they're looking for (which you might be able to think of a way to avoid).

Hope that helps!